# LotusScript - Why do we use array index to access value of text field

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am working on some LotusScript code and came across this syntax to access a text field value: textField(0). I checked this field's properties in the design and it has the type of Text and doesn't allow multiple values. But why do we use the index to access this field value? I need to describe what the code is doing so it makes a difference between "get the value of textField then do something" vs. "get the first element of textField then do something".

Answer (score 2):

The LotusScript expression document.textField is a shorthand form of document.GetItemValue("textField"). As explained in Designer Help, this expression always returns an array of strings for *text or text list* fields. That's why one has to use document.textField(0), or document.GetItemValue("textField")(0) for that matter, to access the first (and possibly only) element in the returned array.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So if a field has Text type and doesn't allow multiple values then I can be sure that this field always contains a single value, not a list?

Comment: See Richard's very comprehensive answer: An item on a document may contain more than one element for various reasons, even if the 'allow multiple values' option is [currently] disabled in the properties of the relevant field on the form.

Answer (score 2):

An important thing to remember is that just because the field properties say that multiple values aren't allowed *today*, they might have been allowed in the past. Nothing gets "fixed up" in old documents if you change the properties in Domino Designer. Your code always has to consider that possibility.

And for that matter, even when the field properties *do* say that multiple values aren't allowed, those properties only apply when a user is editing the document using the defined form. An agent or code using any of the Notes APIs can *always* store multiple values in any text field.

That's why you always access item values through an array. It's not just a matter of "that's how the API works". It's a matter of how the underlying storage works.

And remember: Notes is schemaless. You have to always assume the following:

- The item that corresponds to the field might not exist.
- The item might be empty even if there's a validation formula that requires it to be filled in.
- The item that corresponds to a text field might not actually be a text item.
- The item can contain a list even if the multi-values property is not checked.